# overwrite existing log file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, log4net

How to "overwrite existing log file" ??? I have tried to set attribute property `<appendToFile value="false" />`. but still log file is not getting overwrite. 
My config file setting is as follow:

```
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <file value="Content/log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="false" />
      <threshold value="ON" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} – %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

please let me know where i am doing mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you might want to use the [FileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.html) rather than the RollingFileAppender. It allows you to overwrite the existing file.

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.html

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="Content/log.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="false" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Set appendToFile to false

The following shows how to write the rollingapender file once per execution, but it will still create a new file per execution:

[From the examples page](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html)

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Content/log.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="false" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} – %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: hey Daniel Dyson ,,, thanks a lots for your reply... but still its not working for me. I have added the same code given by u in my config.. but instead of overwriting the log file its start creating multiple file in Content folder.i want override the information in same file.Please give ur view. Thanks

Comment: hey Daniel ,,, sorry my mistake... its working fine with FileAppender as per referred by u.Thanks a lots.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this:

```
<param name="AppendToFile" value="false" />
<rollingStyle value="Size" />
<maxSizeRollBackups value="0" />
<staticLogFileName value="true" />
```

This config will overwrite the existing log file.

Answer (score 0):

Is overwriting the existing file means you want to keep writing to the same file (like a circular buffer)? If so,

1) You should set maxSizeRollBackups=0.

2) You should also set appendToFile = true

Please try and let us know of your results

Comment: hey Syd thanks for your kind interest. I have added the attributes as per told by u but the log information is still getting appended in file.i want to overwrite the data. Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong.

Comment: @Amit, can you clarify your requirement one more time? Do you want the file to be overwritten instead of being appended to everytime you start your logging process?

Comment: My bad. The second statement is incorrect: should set appendToFile=false. Since this is still not working, let me check my logfiles when I go to work tomorrow. Silly question, but have you restarted IIS?